# Full calendar multiple event event problem with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I've got problem with my fullcalendar,but only on Mozilla Firefox browser.I want to add 2 events:
First on date 17.07 to 20.07 another on 18.07 to 22.07.
My browser in result show me first event on date 17.07 without end date and second correct result .I don't know why :/ in another browsers (chrome,opera) it's looks better.

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            right: '',
            center: '',
            left: ''
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        buttonIcons: {
            prev: 'calendar__prev',
            next: 'calendar__next'
        },
        theme: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: false,
        events: [

        ],

        viewRender: function (view) {
            var calendarDate = $('.calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
            var calendarMonth = calendarDate.month();

            //Set data attribute for header. This is used to switch header images using css
            $('.calendar .fc-toolbar').attr('data-calendar-month', calendarMonth);

            //Set title in page header
            $('.content__title--calendar > h1').html(view.title);
        },

        eventClick: function (event, element) {
            $('#edit-event input[value='+event.className+']').prop('checked', true);
            $('#edit-event').modal('show');
            $('.edit-event__id').val(event.id);
            $('.title').val(event.title);
            $('.description').val(event.description);
            $('.start_date').val(event.start);
            $('.stop_date').val(event.stop);
            $('.user_full_name').val(event.author);

        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            startDate=event.start.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
            stopDate=event.stop.substring(0, 10);
            title = event.title + "<br />"+' [ '+startDate+' ]'  + ' [ '+stopDate+' ] ';
            element.popover({
              title: title,
              trigger: 'hover',
              placement: 'auto',
              container: 'body',
              html: true
            });
        }
    });
```

---

I've got my data from api and editing it on that function.

```
function getApiData(daysInMonth){
    var api_url = $('input[name="apiUrl"]').val();
    api_url = api_url+'/api/eventStart='+y+'-'+m+'-'+'01'+'&eventStop='+y+'-'+m+'-'+daysInMonth;

    $.getJSON(api_url,function(result){

        $.each(result.data,function(key,index){
            bg = event_color(index.category_name)
            if(index.category_name == "Holiday"){
                title = index.category_name+' - '+index.user_name;

                endDate=index.event_stop.substring(0, 10);
                endTime=index.event_stop.substring(10, 19);

                var datePlus1 = endDate.split('-');
                datePlus1[2] = Number(datePlus1[2])+1;

                if(datePlus1[2] > daysInMonth){
                    datePlus1[2] = '01';
                    datePlus1[1] = Number(datePlus1[1])+1;  

                    if(datePlus1[1]<10){
                        end=datePlus1[0]+'-0'+datePlus1[1]+'-'+datePlus1[2];
                    }
                    else{
                        end=datePlus1[0]+'-'+datePlus1[1]+'-'+datePlus1[2];
                    }
                }
                else{
                    end=datePlus1[0]+'-'+datePlus1[1]+'-'+datePlus1[2];
                }

                $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    id: index.id,
                    title: title,
                    start: index.event_start,
                    end: end,
                    stop: index.event_stop,
                    description:index.event_description,
                    author: index.user_full_name,
                    allDay: true,
                    className: bg,
                }, true);
            }
         }
      }
```

`

Comment: Could be a problem with parsing of date strings … show how you actually supply that data to the script.

Comment: Without seeing your actual event data it's impossible to say what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved the problem. Function must add '0' to value day if days < 10 becouse the date looks like this 2019-11-1 instead 2019-11-01.